# Windows 8 server , IIS 7.5 , .net version 4.6 , ASP.NET_SessionId cookies is not reflecting SameSite attribute

Tags: asp.net, windows-8, iis-7.5, samesite

as per recommendations I have written the rewrite rule to set the SameSite attribute for all cookies but that is not helping out. Surprisingly whether I have this rule added or not value for samesite attrigute is always blank. (I was expecting , None or Lax, or strict) .
Does anybody know why any of my cookies is not getting value for samesite attribute? I am trying this on Chrome.
[screen shot from network tab , developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WZOV.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to set SameSite attribut.

First is set in Global.asax page.

```
 protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
       //set samesite and secure should both exist, otherwise it will be blocked
        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Secure = true;
        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].HttpOnly =false;
    }
```

[image]

Second is directly setting in web.config. Add  `<sessionState cookieSameSite="Strict" />` under  `<system.web>`.
[image]

You also can use url rewrite to set, but I don't know your rule and cannot know  what caused rewrite failed.

Note: clear cache and cookie in browser after each modification or use private mode of browser. Otherwise it still show the previous cookie.

Comment: changes in web.config in system.web is supported on higher version of .net. I am using .net 4.6. so that will not help me. Good thig is that I figured out the solution by tweaking the rule where I was adding the same site attribute to asp.net cookie.  Key point were the rule which I was using not identifying the expected value  then I changed it to following which helped me 'code' <rule name="SessionCookieAddNoneHeader">
<match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="(.*)" />

<action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None" />
</rule>
'code'

Comment: `changes in web.config in system.web is supported on higher version of .net.` This is an important point that I did not notice. Thank you for reminding.